# MYSQL: Field in "top level query" unknown in subquery

Tags: mysql

I have a long mysql query which builds a report, the problem I have is that the top level field "a.id" is unknown only to one of the sub queries, this query is a select from a "select with alias". I have set the offending section between comments (highlighted) below. How do I get the top level field recognized in the subquery?

Please note that barring the highlighted select the query works fine and it has as yet not been "enhanced" for efficiency, this is a first quick run to do a POC report.

Further note I have removed all company sensitive data and also indentation to help me with "reading the query in sections", other than that all parts should still link up to form a functional query, (again: barring the offending select). :-)

```
mysql_query("select distinct
a.companyname as MEM,
b.vendorid as VID,
b.alphacode as ALPHA,
b.vendorstate as STATE,
b.exchange as EXC,
(select count(memberid) from compa_memusergroups where memberid = a.id and software = 'A') as A,
(select count(memberid) from compa_memusergroups where memberid = a.id and software = 'B') as B,
(select count(memberid) from compa_memusergroups where memberid = a.id and software = 'C') as C,
(select count(memberid) from compa_memusergroups where memberid = a.id and software = 'D') as D,
(select count(memberid) from compa_memusergroups where memberid = a.id and software = 'E') as E,
(select count(memberid) from compa_memusergroups where memberid = a.id and software = 'F') as F,
(select count(memberid) from compa_memusergroups where memberid = a.id and software = 'G') as G,
(select count(memberid) from compa_memusergroups where memberid = a.id and software = 'H') as H,
(select count(memberid) from compa_memusergroups where memberid = a.id and software = 'I') as I,
(select count(memberid) from compa_memusergroups where memberid = a.id and software = 'J') as J,
(select count(memberid) from compa_memusergroups where memberid = a.id and software = 'K') as K,
(select count(memberid) from compa_memusergroups where memberid = a.id and software = 'L') as L,
(select count(memberid) from compa_memusergroups where memberid = a.id and software = 'M') as M,
REPLACE(REPLACE((select count(memberid) from compa_memconndetails where memberid = a.id and type = 'POP'), '0', 'No'), '1', 'Yes') as POP,
REPLACE(REPLACE(a.editandinfo, '0', ''), '1', 'x') as EDIT,
REPLACE(REPLACE(a.infoonly, '0', ''), '1', 'x') as INFO,
(select count(memberid) from compa_oldconnectivity where memberid = a.id and active = 1) as OLD,
(select count(memberid) from compa_newconnectivity where memberid = a.id and active = 1) as NEW,
(select count(memberid) from compa_ptconnectivity where memberid = a.id and ptactive = 1) as PTVAL,
(select count(memberid) from compa_dcconnectivity where memberid = a.id and dcactive = 1) as DCVAL,
IFNULL((select TRIM(LEADING '0' from substring(sysid,5,2)) from compa_compaconnectivity where memberid = a.id and refid = 'compa1'), 0) as compaLevel1,
IFNULL((select TRIM(LEADING '0' from substring(sysid,5,2)) from compa_compaconnectivity where memberid = a.id and refid = 'compam'), 0) as compaLevel2,
IFNULL((select TRIM(LEADING '0' from substring(sysid,5,2)) from compa_compaconnectivity where memberid = a.id and refid = 'compai'), 0) as compaLevel3,
IFNULL((select TRIM(LEADING '0' from substring(sysid,5,2)) from compa_compaconnectivity where memberid = a.id and refid = 'compan'), 0) as compaLevel4,
IFNULL((select TRIM(LEADING '0' from substring(sysid,5,2)) from compa_compbconnectivity where memberid = a.id and refid = 'compb1'), 0) as compbLevel1,
IFNULL((select TRIM(LEADING '0' from substring(sysid,5,2)) from compa_compbconnectivity where memberid = a.id and refid = 'compbm'), 0) as compbLevel2,
IFNULL((select TRIM(LEADING '0' from substring(sysid,5,2)) from compa_compbconnectivity where memberid = a.id and refid = 'compbi'), 0) as compbLevel3,
IFNULL((select TRIM(LEADING '0' from substring(sysid,5,2)) from compa_compbconnectivity where memberid = a.id and refid = 'compbn'), 0) as compbLevel4,
ROUND(
((
(IFNULL((select SUM(compa_memusersoft.bandwold) from compa_memusersoft
inner join compa_oldconnectivity on compa_memusersoft.acron = compa_oldconnectivity.oldsoft
where compa_oldconnectivity.memberid = a.id and compa_oldconnectivity.oldsoft not in (select acron from compa_memusersoft where type = 'EXT') and compa_oldconnectivity.active = 1), 0)
+ IFNULL((select SUM(compa_memusersoft.bandwnew) from compa_memusersoft
inner join compa_newconnectivity on compa_memusersoft.acron = compa_newconnectivity.newsoft
where compa_newconnectivity.memberid = a.id and compa_newconnectivity.newsoft not in (select acron from compa_memusersoft where type = 'EXT') and compa_newconnectivity.active = 1), 0)
+ (IF ((select count(*) from compa_ptconnectivity where memberid = a.id and ptsoft not in (select acron from compa_memusersoft where type = 'EXT') and compa_ptconnectivity.ptactive = 1) > 0, (select count(*) from compa_ptconnectivity where memberid = a.id and ptsoft not in (select acron from compa_memusersoft where type = 'EXT') and compa_ptconnectivity.ptactive = 1) * 0.020, 0))
+ (IF ((select count(*) from compa_dcconnectivity where memberid = a.id and dcsoft not in (select acron from compa_memusersoft where type = 'EXT') and compa_dcconnectivity.dcactive = 1) > 0, (select count(*) from compa_dcconnectivity where memberid = a.id and dcsoft not in (select acron from compa_memusersoft where type = 'EXT') and compa_dcconnectivity.dcactive = 1) * 0.352, 0)))
+
(IF ((select count(*) from compa_compaconnectivity
inner join compa_oldconnectivity on compa_compaconnectivity.memberid = compa_oldconnectivity.memberid 
where compa_compaconnectivity.memberid = a.id and compa_compaconnectivity.refid = 'compa1' and compa_oldconnectivity.oldsoft not in (select acron from compa_memusersoft where type = 'EXT') and compa_oldconnectivity.active = 1) > 0, 0.470 * 2, 
IF((select count(*) from compa_compaconnectivity
where refid = 'compa1' and memberid = a.id and memberid not in (select memberid from compa_oldconnectivity where memberid = a.id) 
and memberid not in (select memberid from compa_newconnectivity where memberid = a.id) 
and memberid not in (select memberid from compa_ptconnectivity where memberid = a.id) 
and memberid not in (select memberid from compa_dcconnectivity where memberid = a.id)) > 0, 0.470 * 2, 0)))
+
(IF ((select count(*) from compa_compaconnectivity
inner join compa_newconnectivity on compa_compaconnectivity.memberid = compa_newconnectivity.memberid 
where compa_compaconnectivity.memberid = a.id and compa_compaconnectivity.refid = 'compam' and compa_newconnectivity.newsoft not in (select acron from compa_memusersoft where type = 'EXT') and compa_newconnectivity.active = 1) > 0, 0.893 * 2, 
IF((select count(*) from compa_compaconnectivity
where refid = 'compam' and memberid = a.id and memberid not in (select memberid from compa_oldconnectivity where memberid = a.id) 
and memberid not in (select memberid from compa_newconnectivity where memberid = a.id) 
and memberid not in (select memberid from compa_ptconnectivity where memberid = a.id) 
and memberid not in (select memberid from compa_dcconnectivity where memberid = a.id)) > 0, 0.893 * 2, 0)))
+
(IF ((select count(*) from compa_compaconnectivity
inner join compa_oldconnectivity on compa_compaconnectivity.memberid = compa_oldconnectivity.memberid 
where compa_compaconnectivity.memberid = a.id and compa_compaconnectivity.refid = 'compai' and compa_oldconnectivity.oldsoft not in (select acron from compa_memusersoft where type = 'EXT') and compa_oldconnectivity.active = 1) > 0, 0.512 * 2, 
IF((select count(*) from compa_compaconnectivity
where refid = 'compai' and memberid = a.id and memberid not in (select memberid from compa_oldconnectivity where memberid = a.id) 
and memberid not in (select memberid from compa_newconnectivity where memberid = a.id) 
and memberid not in (select memberid from compa_ptconnectivity where memberid = a.id) 
and memberid not in (select memberid from compa_dcconnectivity where memberid = a.id)) > 0, 0.512 * 2, 0)))
+
(IF ((select count(*) from compa_compaconnectivity
inner join compa_oldconnectivity on compa_compaconnectivity.memberid = compa_oldconnectivity.memberid 
where compa_compaconnectivity.memberid = a.id and compa_compaconnectivity.refid = 'compan' and compa_oldconnectivity.oldsoft not in (select acron from compa_memusersoft where type = 'EXT') and compa_oldconnectivity.active = 1) > 0, 0.512 * 2, 
IF((select count(*) from compa_compaconnectivity
where refid = 'compan' and memberid = a.id and memberid not in (select memberid from compa_oldconnectivity where memberid = a.id) 
and memberid not in (select memberid from compa_newconnectivity where memberid = a.id) 
and memberid not in (select memberid from compa_ptconnectivity where memberid = a.id) 
and memberid not in (select memberid from compa_dcconnectivity where memberid = a.id)) > 0, 0.512 * 2, 0)))
+
(IF ((select count(*) from compa_compbconnectivity inner join compa_oldconnectivity on compa_compbconnectivity.memberid = compa_oldconnectivity.memberid 
where compa_compbconnectivity.memberid = a.id and compa_oldconnectivity.oldsoft not in (select acron from compa_memusersoft where type = 'EXT') and compa_oldconnectivity.active = 1) > 0, 0.512 * 2, 
IF((select count(*) from compa_compbconnectivity inner join compa_newconnectivity on compa_compbconnectivity.memberid = compa_newconnectivity.memberid 
where compa_compbconnectivity.memberid = a.id and compa_newconnectivity.newsoft not in (select acron from compa_memusersoft where type = 'EXT') and compa_newconnectivity.active = 1) > 0, 0.512 * 2, 0)))
+
(IF((select count(*) from compa_compbconnectivity where memberid = a.id and memberid not in (select memberid from compa_oldconnectivity where memberid = a.id) 
and memberid not in (select memberid from compa_newconnectivity where memberid = a.id) 
and memberid not in (select memberid from compa_ptconnectivity where memberid = a.id) 
and memberid not in (select memberid from compa_dcconnectivity where memberid = a.id)) > 0, 0.512 * 2, 0))
+

/*------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
IFNULL((select SUM(bandwreq * mplsterm) from (
select compa_memusersoft.acron, compa_memusersoft.bandwreq, compa_memconndetails.mplsterm from compa_memusersoft
inner join compa_memconndetails on compa_memusersoft.acron = compa_memconndetails.software
where compa_memusersoft.acron in (select oldsoft from compa_oldconnectivity where memberid = a.id)
or compa_memusersoft.acron in (select newsoft from compa_newconnectivity where memberid = a.id)
or compa_memusersoft.acron in (select ptsoft from compa_ptconnectivity where memberid = a.id)
or compa_memusersoft.acron in (select dcsoft from compa_dcconnectivity where memberid = a.id)
and compa_memconndetails.type = 'EXT' and compa_memconndetails.memberid = a.id group by compa_memusersoft.acron) tblval), 0)
*/-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

)
/ (70 / 100)
), 3) as REQBANDW,
(IFNULL((select pribandw1 from compa_currmembandw where memberid = a.id), 0) + IFNULL((select pribandw2 from compa_currmembandw where memberid = a.id), 0) +
IFNULL((select secbandw1 from compa_currmembandw where memberid = a.id), 0) + IFNULL((select secbandw2 from compa_currmembandw where memberid = a.id), 0) +
IFNULL((select backbandw1 from compa_currmembandw where memberid = a.id), 0) + IFNULL((select backbandw2 from compa_currmembandw where memberid = a.id), 0)) as CURRBANDW,
a.env
from
compa_member a
inner join compa_memberconnectivity b on a.id = b.memberid
order by a.env desc, a.companyname");
```

Comment: The subquery in the offending part doesn't make much sense to me. You are grouping by `acron` but also retrieving other columns, one of them belonging to the joined table too. You should realise that if the join produces more than one row per acron and you are pulling non-aggregated values that do not participate in grouping, those values are going to be random. And to top it all, the outer subquery performs calculations (`SUM(compa_memusersoft.bandwreq * compa_memconndetails.mplsterm)`) on those potentially random values. Is this by design?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest modifying the offending part like this:

```
IFNULL(
  (
    /*select SUM(bandwreq * mplsterm)
    from (*/
      select /*compa_memusersoft.acron,*/ SUM(compa_memusersoft.bandwreq * compa_memconndetails.mplsterm)
      from compa_memusersoft
      inner join compa_memconndetails on compa_memusersoft.acron = compa_memconndetails.software
      where compa_memusersoft.acron in (select oldsoft from compa_oldconnectivity where memberid = a.id)
         or compa_memusersoft.acron in (select newsoft from compa_newconnectivity where memberid = a.id)
         or compa_memusersoft.acron in (select ptsoft  from compa_ptconnectivity  where memberid = a.id)
         or compa_memusersoft.acron in (select dcsoft  from compa_dcconnectivity  where memberid = a.id)
        and compa_memconndetails.type = 'EXT'
        and compa_memconndetails.memberid = a.id
      group by compa_memusersoft.acron
    /*) tblval*/
  ),
  0
)
```

Comment: Many thanks Andriy, your suggestion worked fine except it returned more than one row, I then "grouped" all the "or selects" into one select distinct and with your changes it worked perfectly. Thank you for the help, much appreciated. (Now to sit and optimize the whole thing!!!)